# Can I remove the bash subprocesses from this command without using a loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, macos

This is a purely aesthetic question, as I have a working command now, but I'd like to run `wc -m` against each element in my clients array without an explicit loop or running a subshell/child shell process. Bash is v5.0.18 running on macOS.

```
clients=(one two three)
printf '%s\n' "${clients[@]}" | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo -n {} | wc -m' | sort -nr | head -1
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not wanting to use a loop?

Comment: @glennjackman like I said, pure aesthetics.

Comment: Your code will break if `clients` contain unbalanced quotes, parentheses or any other shell control characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more googling, I found this nice piece of awk script:

`printf '%s\n' "${clients[@]}" | awk '{print length}' | sort -nr | head -1`

Comment: You might want to make your awk program a little longer and get rid of the sort and head. ` printf ... | awk 'length>=l { l=length;} END {print l}'`

Comment: @icarus while that's a good suggestion, the sort/head part is actually just a stand-in for the rest of the code I have there, to help prevent someone suggesting something that didn't output the same values.

Answer (score 1):

I find functions quite pleasing, if you're open to a non-one-liner solution:

```bsh
length() {
    echo ${#1}
}
map() {
    func=$1
    shift
    for arg; do
        $func "$arg"
    done
}
max() { 
    read -r max
    while read -r arg; do
        (( arg > max )) && max=$arg
    done
    echo $max
}
```

and then

```bsh
map length "${clients[@]}" | max
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a pipeline is to execute a command in a subshell. You can avoid it like this with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS="[[:space:]]" 'length > len {len = length} END {print len}' <<<${clients[@]}
```

GNU `awk` only:

```
awk -v RS="[[:space:]]" '{D[NR]=length}; END {asort(D); print D[NR]}' <<<${clients[@]}
```